# Is there a way to disable org.junit.runner.JUnitCore's stdout output?

Tags: java, bash, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I want to run some Unit tests via a script using [JUnit 4's JUnitCore](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html).
The script is rather easy:

```
java -cp "bin:lib/*" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore my.Tests
```

The "problem" is that I would like to process the output of my tests (written to stdout and stderr), and the runner itself adds output to stdout (like a single "." (dot) after each test).

Is there a way to prevent the runner's output (i.e., quiet JUnitCore's default output)? Filtering those dots is kind of annoying.

Comment: As the questions states, there is some output already generated that must be processed. So suppressing everything will not be useful i guess!?

Comment: @Inian: loonytune is right, I have some output that I want to process. I just want the default output to be turned off.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger: A bit of `bash` manipulation with something like `java -cp "bin:lib/*" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore my.Tests | while read line; do echo "${line//./}"; done`

Comment: This also removes dots in my output. As I am writing floating point numbers (using a dot for the decimal), this will not work.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger : Can you a bit more specific by giving a sample input and expected output like for e.g you want to remove dot at end of line.

Comment: Pewh, this may differ a bit from test to test. Mostly it will be "TestClassName;TestName;Success;Runtime;SomeAdditionalInfo..." per test method. But I asked a very general question on purpose, because I don't really want the answer to be problem-specific. I have a solution that works for the moment, but only for my current specific case. It may not work on future projects with different output, and that's why I wanted to turn off JUnit's default output completly.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [JUnitCore](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java), you could write your own main-wrapper, which just uses another `JUnitSystem` and calls `runMain` from `JUnitCore`, e.g.:

```
Result result = new JUnitCore().runMain(new NoopPrintStreamSystem(), args);
System.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);
```

You can then implement the `NoopPrintStreamSystem` depending on your needs, e.g. with a `PrintStream` doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Roland's answer I'll provide my opinion. First - I don't think you should use System.out/System.err in your code, even in Unit Tests. I'll raise two main reasons (more relevant for tests):

- Performance (the logging system plugged and set up correctly will make unit tests running significantly faster)
- Inflexibility of processing - you can set up the logging system to stream the output into file or something and later process it. In CI you can create a No-Op implementation of logging system (binding) and it will be probably the fastest way to run them. The point is that you can decide.

For example, you can use slf4j system- use api module in tests (only interfaces of logger classes) and 2 relevant binding:

- simple binding (redirect to files)
- no-op binding  - don't print anything

In production code you can use real binding to real logging system of your choice.

Now, if you absolutely need to redirect the `System.out` and `System.err` to another place (say file) there is an old technique:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new WhatEverOutputStreamYouWant()));
System.setErr(__Just__the__same__as__above__)
```

You can write some JUnit Rule that will be invoked for each TestCase and you'll be set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I need to write to stdout / stderr, because the output of the script is read by another tool, and this tool relies on the script's stdout / stderr output. Otherwise, I would use a concrete logger system. :)

Comment: Or, in this case you probably do want to use the Concrete logging system. Just assign 2 different appenders to the same logger - out would write to stdout/stderr and another one will be file appender that will produce files. You'll be later able to process them in your project. Does it help?

Answer (score -1):

As simple as:

```
addListener(new MyTextListener(System.out));
```

Overriding the TextListener.testStarted Method:

```
private class MyTextListener extends TextListener {

    public MyTextListener(PrintStream writer) {
        super(writer);
    }

    @Override
    public void testStarted(Description description) {

    }
}
```